# UMVUE of $g(\mu)=2\mu$ for a normal distribution

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be iid observations from a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, $\sigma^2>0$ is known and $\mu$ is an unknown real number. Let $g(\mu)=2\mu$ be the parameter of interest.
I know that $(\bar X,S^2)$ is a complete sufficient statistics for ($\mu$,$\sigma^2$) where $\bar X$ is the sample mean and $S^2$ is the sample variance. I am a little confused here. How do I find the UMVUE of $g(\mu)$?

Comment: It is unclear where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: UMVUE of $\mu$ is $\bar X$ so UMVUE of $2\mu$ is  $2\bar X.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Lehmann-Shceffé Theorem](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/Stat/StatLec16-20.pdf), if $T$ is a Sufficient and Complete statistics for $\mu$ and $T^{*}$ $=$ $h(T)$ is unbiased for $g(\mu)$, then $T^{*}$ is UMVUE for $g(\mu)$.

The theorem applies to your case since $T$ $=$ $\overline{X}$ is Sufficient and Complete for $\mu$, hence $T^{*}$ = $2$$\overline{X}$ is UMVUE for $g(\mu)$ = $2$$\mu$.